# Why does my shell prompt disappear when I install vim 7.4?

Tags: vim, centos

I'm using CentOS 6. Since the CentOS repos have an older version of vim (7.2), I have compiled my own. However, I am having a weird issue. After running and exiting vim, I've found that my shell prompt has disappeared. Also, when I type, it does not appear in the terminal, nor does any output. What's weird is that it looks as though *something* is being outputted, since the cursor will move down the screen, but I can't *see* anything.

It must have something to do with compiling an X version, because it does *not* happen when I compile vim without X windows support (but I would like to have gvim, too). Here are the configuration options I supplied when compiling:

```
./configure --prefix=$OPT/Cellar/vim/7.4 --with-features=huge --enable-gui=auto --with-x --enable-xim
```

I also tried compiling without Xim. I've also tried explicitly setting `--enable-gui=gtk2` (which is what gvim 7.2 from the CentOS repos uses).

I am using KDE4. The problem occurs both when running tcsh and bash. I have tried with `$TERM` set to both `xterm` and `xterm-256color` as well.

Additionally, running neither `reset` nor `stty sane` restores the shell to its proper behavior.

Any idea why my prompt disappears when running vim? As I missing a config flag or some other compilation issue?

Comment: This might be a better fit at SuperUser or Programmers

Comment: Superuser yes, certainly not Programmers.

Comment: Does running `reset` or `stty sane` fix the prompt? If so it sounds like vim is failing to restore the prompt modes/config correctly.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Oh yes, I forgot to mention that--neither of those restore the shell to its proper behavior. (Updating my question to mention that.)

Comment: Does the same occur when backgrounding vim? (`vim & ; fg ; C-z` etc) Are commands running but not visible? (`echo hi > ~/test`) Did you try re-sourcing your shell config (`source ~/.bashrc`)? You could also check if `vim` is a script or an binary (if you're building your own I'd expect a binary). Running $OPT/Cellar/vim/7.4/vim has the same result? (to ensure you're running the built binary)

Comment: @idbrii: Launching (or putting vim) in the background does not solve the glitch, nor does re-sourcing the shell config (in tcsh _or_ bash). Commands _are_ being run though.

Comment: What does vim think the terminal is when you are in vim? `:verbose set term?`

Comment: @FDinoff: `xterm-256color`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ultimately traced this down to an error in my `~/.vimrc` file. I had some lines like this:

```
if has('gui_running')
  # Gvim customization
endif

if has('gui_gtk2')
  # GTK2-specific Gvim customization
endif
```

The second block was running every time vim loaded. Because it changed some window geometry, it ended up messing up bash; when I dropped back to bash, bash thought it only had ~53 columns to work with (and possibly some other things were messed up).

Solution: The second `if` block should be inside the first.

Comment: Alternative solution is to put that code into a gvimrc

Comment: What was the second block doing exactly?

Comment: @EtanReisner: Setting lines, columns, and guifont.

Comment: I figured it was lines and columns but I didn't see how that would do this (without actually changing the size of your window which I figure you would have noticed). You might want to include those lines in the answer as they are material detail.